Django Haitian Creole
I want to make a Django Project in Haitian Creole
I am trying to create a django project in Haitian Creole.  I put
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ht'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

in the settings.py
I had installed gettext and run the follow command in my project folder
django-admin makemessages -l ht

But everytime I run my server it returns an error.
Can somebody help me with this please?

Please edit your question and include full details of the failing code, and the error message.
